# Is it possible to make a polar plot the xy-plane of my 3D projection?

Tags: python, matplotlib, 3d, polar-coordinates, spherical-coordinate

I'm trying to plot a basic form of the solar system with the Sun at its origin. Since I like the labelling of a polar plot, I'm already able to nicely visualise the longitudes and radial distances of the planetary bodies w.r.t. Sun. Now, I want to display also their latitudes (how far above/below the polar plot the planets are). Any suggestions please?

I'm trying to insert a polar plot in my 3D projection? Please find below my code.

**NOTE:** If there is a completely different way to go about this, please let me know. It's only the (polar/spherical) labelling system which I'm interested in.

```
# Imports
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# Positions (lon [deg], lat [deg], radius [AU]) 
sun = [0, 0, 0]
earth = [0, -4.31, 0.98]
target = [121, 15.66, 2.03]  

# Plot
fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.subplot(1, 1, 1, projection='3d')

plt.polar(np.deg2rad(sun[0]), sun[2], 'o', label='Sun')
plt.polar(np.deg2rad(earth[0]), earth[2],  'o', label='Earth')    
plt.polar(np.deg2rad(target[0]), target[2],  '.', label = 'target')

plt.legend(loc = 'lower left')
ax.set_rticks([0.5, 1, 1.5, 2, 2.5])  
ax.set_rlabel_position(285) 
plt.show()
```

[image: Here is my plot output]